# MySQL: Output rows created from columns containing delimited data

Tags: mysql, sql, cytoscape

Assuming I have the following data in a MySQL:

```
**bond** | **node** | **edges**
foo      |    1     |    2,3
hak      |    2     |    1
wat      |    3     |    1,2
```

I wish to return results to create data suitable for visualisation in Cytoscape. It requires that each node have a line devoted to each edge. The output would look like:

```
**bond** | **node** | **edges**
foo      |    1     |    2
foo      |    1     |    3
hak      |    2     |    1
wat      |    3     |    1
wat      |    3     |    2
```

I think the PIVOT operator might work somehow, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** you have an edge master table where in all possible values for edges are stored.

If my assumption is wrong, my answer will not hold good

```
SELECT bond, node, edgemaster.edgeid FROM mytable
JOIN edgemaster ON FIND_IN_SET(edgemaster.edgeid, mytable.edges)
ORDER BY bond, node, edgemaster.edgeid
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9118/1)

Comment: Solution provided produced desired results, joining entries from 'mytable' to a master table of edges. Thank you.